# How to modify the variables such that fbx object is viewable on phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, fbx

am facing this issue now. Managed to successfully load up a fbx model onto phone 7. Unfortunately, the model seems to appear oversized on the screen and a huge part of the model goes off screen. I suspect changes could be made to the following codes but as I have no experience on this, I do now know where to begin. Please advise. Alternatively, would it help if I minimize the resolution/size of the fbx model? Thank you!

```
// set up the "camera"
        Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
        Vector3 cameraTarget = Vector3.Zero;
        Vector3 cameraUp = Vector3.UnitY;
        float nearClippingDistance = 0.1f;  // anything closer to cameraPosition than this won't be drawn
        float farClippingDistance = 1000f;  // anything farther from cameraPosition than this won't be drawn
        float fieldOfView = MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f); // the vertical angle the "camera" can see
        float aspectRatio = (float)graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / (float)graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight;

        world = Matrix.Identity;    // the model's transform; setting it to the identity means it will display at (0,0,0) with no rotation or scaling
        view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraTarget, cameraUp);     // put the camera at cameraPosition, looking at cameraTarget, with cameraUp as the vector pointing to the "sky"
        projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(fieldOfView, aspectRatio*40, nearClippingDistance, farClippingDistance);  // defines the perspective

        // set up the alternative cull mode so that our model draws properly
        RasterizerState rs = new RasterizerState();
        rs.CullMode = CullMode.CullClockwiseFace;
        GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rs;
```

Comment: Do let me know if more information is required on my part to clarify. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found the answer. Problem lies with the camera position.

Simply edit the 3rd parameter in Vector object, change it to 15.

```
Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(1, 1, 15);
```

What this does it that it moves the camera further away from the object, essentially making it appear smaller.

Problem solved.